# How can i string format double value to relative to other binding value?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a View Model which contain a collection. Each collection item have instrument and price properties. Instrument object has Name and decimal place numbers property.

When i bind collection to my View's DataGrid control, i want to format price column relative to item's instrument decimal place numbers property like below;

**AAPL 100.89** decimal places number is 2 for AAPL

**EURUSD 1.12345** decimal places number is 5 for EURUSD

How can i write this type dynamic converter? Or is there a better solution for this?

Comment: I don't work with DataGrid much, but can you use a converter with `Binding PropertyToFormat, Converter={StaticResource yourConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding OtherProperty}`? If you need to use more than 2 properties, you will have to use a `MultiBinding`.

Comment: @Kilazur, after ask a question actually i think like you. First i try to do with binding with converter parameter but i failed. Received an error that can not do binding to converter parameter because it's not a dependency property. After that i try to second way that multi binding and my problem is solved. I'll answer my question with code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answer a question, i want to give a detail about problem. I have a WatchListItem class that have Instrument, Last Price, Bid Price, Ask Price properties. In my View Model there is WatchListItems property which is list of WatchListItem and i'm binding it to my View's DataGrid Control. DataGrid control have 3 columns for each property. At the runtime i want to show Last, Ask and Bid prices with format according to instrument's tick size.

After search a little bit i see this problem can be solved both Binding and Multi Binding.

If you want to use Binding you have to bind column to WatchListItem. Then you can write class that implement IValueConverter and use it in xaml via static resource and also for converter know that which price want to format you have to give convert parameter "Last" or "Bid" or "Ask". I don't like this solution because open for misspellings about convert parameter.

I used MultiBinding and IMultiValueConverter like below.

**Converter**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(string))]
public class PriceToStringConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region Implementation of IMultiValueConverter

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(string))
            throw new ArgumentException("The target type must be a string.");

        var instrument = (IInstrument) values[0];
        var instrumentPrice = (double) values[1];
        var instrumentTickSizeParts = instrument.TickSize.ToString("0.#####", culture).Split('.');
        if (instrumentTickSizeParts.Length == 1)
            return instrumentPrice.ToString(culture);

        var format = $"0.{string.Empty.PadRight(instrumentTickSizeParts[1].Length, '0')}";
        return instrumentPrice.ToString(format, culture);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**XAML**

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentWatchList.WatchListItems}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <converters:PriceToStringConverter x:Key="PriceToStringConverter"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Instrument" Binding="{Binding Instrument.Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Time, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm:ss}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PriceToStringConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Instrument"/>
                        <Binding Path="Last"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bid">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PriceToStringConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Instrument"/>
                        <Binding Path="Bid"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ask">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PriceToStringConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Instrument"/>
                        <Binding Path="Ask"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```